# how to create a function using CUBEMEMBERPROPERTY?

Tags: vba, excel, cube

I can't get my head around making this as a `function` rather than typing everything. This is a member-function i created.

```
Public Function cSalesChannel(Optional s As Integer)
If s > 0 Then
    cSalesChannel = "[DimGeography].[Location].[SalesChannel].&[" & s & "]"
Else
    cSalesChannel = "[DimGeography].[Location].[Country].[England]"
End If
End Function
```

A cubememberproperty also has `property`, that's where I get stuck.

```
 Public Function cRegion(Optional s As Integer)
If s > 0 Then
    cRegion = "[DimGeography].[Location].[SalesChannel].&[" & s & "];[DimGeography].[Location].[SalesChannel].[Region]"
Else
    cRegion = "[DimGeography].[Location].[Country].[England]"
End If
End Function
```

I cant get that separator `;`and the `property`done correctly.

all help is great

Comment: Could you give an example of what the cRegion function should return for values of s > 0? And also the actual return value when you call it with that value of s > 9? That'll help us to figure out what's not working right.

Comment: The s<0 returns a store name. When using the function it's connected to a OLAP-cube. The problem ain't the return but the fact that I can't figure out how to get the separator and the last part (property) in there. The return will in the end be a region.